# Extending Windows search index with a filter handler that works with a custom file format using C#/.NET

Tags: c#, windows, filter, indexing, handlers

Is It possible to extend Windows search index with a filter handler that works with a custom file format in .NET/C#?

I want the indexing to work for some custom file types. For some custom file formats, I need to implement a filter or property handler to have file content and properties indexed.

I googled it to get some samples relating to it but I could not find anything useful. Although I got an article from msdn which talks about extending the indexes for windows.

> [Windows Search Developer's Guide - Extending the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318649%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Can anyone help me get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing this.

Not because I say so, but because Microsoft does [MSDN: IFilter interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266451%28VS.85%29.aspx).

A quote :

> Important  In Windows 7 and later, filters written in managed code are explicitly blocked. Filters MUST be written in native code due to potential CLR versioning issues with the process that multiple add-ins run in.

If you decide not to use Windows 7, you can still use one of the implementation frameworks like [iFilterCode](http://ifiltercore.codeplex.com/) to make one. But it will have to go through Interop all the time which is a pretty decent hit in speed.

Comment: It's fine to do this so long as you use .net 4.0

Comment: I have looked into this in the past and haven't seen any mention of that. Where did you see that?

Comment: Lot's of the documentation is out of date but web search will reveal that what I state is correct.

Comment: @jaapjan: Sir, I had gone through the specified article before posting this question and had the same doubt in my mind but they had given there a sample in C# which uses the microsoft indexing service to search for a specified word in the catalog created under the indexing service of microsoft.

Comment: I ran that sample after creating a catalog in my indexing service and it ran finely.

Comment: @David: Sir, Can u please give me some link in support of ur comment

Comment: +1, I remember reading the same even without mentioning Windows 7 - just "IFilter must be in unmanaged code".

Answer (score -2):

I believe that Acrobat provides an iFilter interface, and I can use that to search inside of PDFs using MS SQL Server Full-Text-Search.

Comment: I know that sir but I wanted to use this iFilter interface(or any other thing for that matter) for any custom file format and extend the indexing in windows.Thanks.

Comment: are you using 'windows desktop search'?

Comment: @Aaron: Sir, I wanted to create a filter handler in C# which looks for contents in any custom file format that's all.

Comment: @Aaron: Windows Search(in windows vista & windows7) replaces Windows Desktop Search (WDS), which was available as an add-in for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. I basically want to add a filter handler to this windows search. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I just think that Microsoft search SUCKS.  I used to be able to go Start, Search *Korn*.mp3 - now this same functionality doesn't work any longer.